# Why doesn't any jQuery code and some icons work after loading the partial view in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I have a page with a list of information, and I can search this information using a series of fields and Ajax. I can reload the information on the page by loading it as a partial view. However, after the page is reloaded, no jQuery code works. What could be the issue?

Code in C#:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> InvoiceSearch(string CurrentPage, string createDate, int? id,
    int? remoteFactorNumber, string deliverToPhoneNumber, int? statusInvoice)
{
    try
    {
        var branchId = 0;

        if (!User.IsInRole(ConstantRoles.Admin))
        {
            branchId = User.Identity.GetBranchId();
        }

        var invoiceParams = new BranchInvoicesResourceParameters
        {
            PageNumber = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentPage) ? Convert.ToInt32(CurrentPage) : 1,
            CreateDateTime = createDate?.ToEnglishNumbers() ?? null,
            InvoiceId = id,
            RemoteFactorId = remoteFactorNumber,
            StatusInvoice = statusInvoice == null ? null : (StatusInvoice)statusInvoice,
            DeliverToPhoneNumber = deliverToPhoneNumber?.ToEnglishNumbers() ?? null,
            BranchId = branchId,
        };

        var branchInvoice = await _invoiceService.GetBranchInvoices(invoiceParams);
       
        return PartialView("_BranchInvoiceList", branchInvoice.Data);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Ajax call:

```
function getSearchInvoice(page) {

    var createDate = $('#searchCreateDate').val();
    var id = $('#searchId').val();
    var remoteFactorNumber = $('#searchRemoteFactorNumber').val();
    var deliverToPhoneNumber = $('#searchDeliverToPhoneNumber').val();
    var statusInvoice = $('#searchStatusInvoice').val();

    var invoice = new Object();
    invoice.createDate = createDate;
    invoice.id = id;
    invoice.remoteFactorNumber = remoteFactorNumber;
    invoice.deliverToPhoneNumber = deliverToPhoneNumber;
    invoice.statusInvoice = statusInvoice;

    $.ajax({
        type: "Get",
        url: "@Url.Action("InvoiceSearch", "Home")",
        headers: {
            "RequestVerificationToken": requestVerificationToken
        },
        data: {
            CurrentPage: page,
            createDate: createDate,
            id: id,
            remoteFactorNumber: remoteFactorNumber,
            deliverToPhoneNumber: deliverToPhoneNumber,
            statusInvoice: statusInvoice
        },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (response) {
          
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
     
    });
};
```

If I refresh the page, there is no problem, but when I retrieve the partial view again through Ajax, no jQuery code works.

Comment: What do you mean by no jquery code works after retrieving partial view? Like the jquery code in partial view doesn't work or the code from main view doesn't work? Please provide more detail. Anyway, since the partial view is added after initial load make sure that your code only runs after the partial view existed in DOM.

Comment: OR at least use the concept of event deligation using `.on(`

Comment: I have a button that triggers an AJAX call to activate a specific record when clicked. However, after loading the partial view, that jQuery function is no longer being invoked.
` <a href="#" id="asyncBranchInvoice@(item.Id)"  class="btn btn-sm btn-warning d-md-block btn-event-disable" data-invoiceid="@item.Id"
    data-remotefactornumber="@item.RemoteFactorNumber">
     تلاش مجدد <i class="ms-50 "
                  data-feather="rotate-cw"></i><i class="load-icon ms-50"></i>`

`

Comment: Did you see any error inside the F12 development tool console? Besides, how you call the `getSearchInvoice` function inside your page? If possible, please share the an example which could let us reproduce the issue then we could find out the reason more easily.

Answer (score 0):

put all the query code in

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery code gets executed before the partial view has been loaded.
In other words, the selector which you used was not even available in DOM at the first place.

Better to use

```
$(document).ready(function() { //code });
```

Or, you could simply move your code related to partial view to a separate script and load it along with the partial view.